# How to show that $n \sin(\frac1n) \gt0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I show that $a_{n} := n\,\sin(\frac{1}{n}) \ge 0\; \forall\; n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I know already that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\,a_{n} = 1$ and that $0 < a_{1} < 1$. So I assume I only have to show now that $a_{n}$ is monotonously increasing, i.e. $a_{n+1} \ge a_{n}$.

I start with $(n+1)\,\sin(\frac{1}{n+1}) \ge n\,\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ but I don't really get anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although your claim is correct, I don't see why you don't simply solve the problem by using that $$\sin(x)>0, \forall x\in(0,\pi)$$

Comment: Great, thanks. This is really much easier. Is it a good way to prove that sin(x) > 0 (between 0 and pi) by integrating and finding a positive Integral value between 0 and pi?

Comment: The way you would like to show the result I claim is not correct. But I don't think it is something you have to show independently, just use it.

Comment: @djun that method would not prove that the function is strictly positive on the interval $(0,\pi )$, it just means that the area is positive (there is more positive than negative). If you feel the need to prove this fact, find the roots of $\sin (x)$ on the interval $[0,\pi ]$ and then see what sign the function is for values $x\in (0,\pi )$